# Ensure shell script is launched with correct shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Our shell script's first line reads

```
#!/bin/bash
```

According to my (limited) Linux shell knowledge this causes to use `/bin/bash` to launch the application when the user invokes this script directly, e.g., using

```
$ ./myscript.sh
```

Unfortunately, the script works *not* as expected, when the user launches it using

```
$ sh ./myscript.sh
```

How can I catch the case that the "wrong" shell executes this script and show the user an appropriate error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case "$BASH" in
  *bash) :;;
  *) echo >&2 "$0: please run this with bash."; exit 1;;
esac
```

Or you could just do it for them:

```
case "$BASH" in
  *bash) :;;
  *) exec bash "$0" "$@";;
esac
```